# Time frame in excel

Tags: forms

i would like to know if it’s possible to have a formula for  Time Frame. For example: I have an Excel file regarding some emails that came on different hours of a day. So i would to regroup them by time frame of Half an hour. (12 AM t0o 12H29 AM, 12H30 AM to 12H50 AM etc). So if a email came in at 12H05 AM, it will go under 12H00 AM to 12H20 AM. If one came in at 1H10 PM it will be under 1h00 PM-1H9 PM.   Is it possible?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In order to group the dates by minutes, I would create a pivot table with a group by on the date. Within the properties it gives the options for the data ranges which you could use 30 minute interval.

Comment: Hi, i did create a PIVOT table however, i want have total of cases (emails) per half an hour. So basically how cases (Emails) i got between 6 AM and 6H29 AM. how do i do it?

Comment: Right click the high level label and click group... Here you will be able to specify the group by with minutes.

Comment: I cant post pictures but this link will step you through it. http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/17/group-dates-in-pivot-tables/